# MongoDB Java Driver Aggregation Pipeline: Static Aggregates vs "new Document()"

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'm trying to create a pipeline with the static Aggregates methods.

This doesn't work:

```
List<Bson> lookupPipeline = Arrays.asList(match(eq("email", "$$user_email")));


AggregateIterable<Document> result = db.getCollection("users").aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        lookup("comments", Arrays.asList(new Variable("user_email", "$email")), lookupPipeline, "comments"
                ),
         project(fields(include("_id", "name", "email", "comments"), computed("count", new Document("$size", "$comments")))),
         sort(descending("count")),
         limit(20)
        ));
```

While this does work:

```java
AggregateIterable<Document> result = db.getCollection("users").aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$lookup",
                        new Document("from", "comments")
                                .append("let",
                                        new Document("user_email", "$email"))
                                .append("pipeline", Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
                                        new Document("$expr",
                                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$email", "$$user_email"))))))
                                .append("as", "comments")),
                new Document("$project",
                        new Document("_id", 1L)
                                .append("name", 1L)
                                .append("email", 1L)
                                .append("comments", 1L)
                                .append("count",
                                        new Document("$size", "$comments"))),
                new Document("$sort",
                        new Document("count", -1L))));
```

**Edit**

This is the pipeline I'm trying to build:

```
[{$lookup: {
    from: 'comments',
    let: {"user_email": "$email"},
    pipeline: [
      {$match: 
        {$expr: {$eq: ["$email", "$$user_email"]
      }
      }
    }],
    as: 'comments'
    }
  }, 
{$project: {
  _id: 1, 
  name: 1, 
  email: 1, 
  comments: 1,
  count: {$size: "$comments"}
  }},
{$sort: {
  count: -1
  }
}]
```

users collection:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59b99db4cfa9a34dcd7885b6"
    },
    "name": "Ned Stark",
    "email": "sean_bean@gameofthron.es",
    "password": "$2b$12$UREFwsRUoyF0CRqGNK0LzO0HM/jLhgUCNNIJ9RJAqMUQ74crlJ1Vu"
}
```

comments collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a9427648b0beebeb69579cc"
    },
    "name": "Andrea Le",
    "email": "andrea_le@fakegmail.com",
    "movie_id": {
        "$oid": "573a1390f29313caabcd418c"
    },
    "text": "Rem officiis eaque repellendus amet eos doloribus. Porro dolor voluptatum voluptates neque culpa molestias. Voluptate unde nulla temporibus ullam.",
    "date": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1332804016000"
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the mistake in the first option?
Part of the problem is, that I cannot find a good documentation for the Aggregates methods. 
The java driver documentation only has very minimalistic examples.

Comment: What is the `lookupPipeline` in the first query? What version of Java Driver?

Comment: Ah sorry, i added the lookupPipeline. 

Version of Java Driver: `mongodb-driver-sync 3.9.1`

Comment: In the `$lookup` you are matching `users` and `comments` collection _email_ fields? You don't need the lookup's _pipeline_ to match equality condition.

Comment: What do you mean by that? 
My goal: After the `$lookup` stage, I want to have an array field in my document which contains all comments for the specific user.

Comment: Yes, that is the likely result. It helps if you post a sample document with relevant fields from both the collections.

Comment: I edited the post and added the pipeline I'm trying to build and examples for both collections.

Comment: You can use the following `localField: "email", foreignField: "email"` _instead of_ `let: ...., pipeliene: [ ...]` syntax. I suggest you run the code with both syntaxes in the `mongo` shell and verify the results.

Comment: I guess that works as well. 
My question was about the syntax for the `Aggregates` methods and how to build the pipeline with them.

Comment: [Aggregates.lookup](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/builders/aggregation/) in the examples of Java Driver documentation - should be enough, I think. Also, try to get a newer driver version, if you dont have already.